# Intellisense not working in VS 2013 community edition

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I have installed VS 2013 community edition. It seems that the intellisense is not working properly. Nothing happens on pressing "tab" key. I have to explicitly press "ctrl + space" keys to get the intellisense working. Anyone else facing similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

This might solve the issue for you:

go to Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> All Languages >> General and make sure that both Auto list members and Parameter information are checked (not the half-checked/square state).

[image]

Soruce: http://omegacoder.com/?p=1008